# Self-signed certificate

Tags: java, android, ssl-certificate, ksoap2

I use a hosting with a self-signed certificate. So I downloaded the certificate from my domain https://www.marpel.cz/ and created .bks file using http://portecle.sourceforge.net/.

I need to establish the https connection and retrieve data from my webservice. I use ksoap2 library. I have copied and used a class [ConnectionWithSelfSignedCertificate](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/wiki/CodingTipsAndTricks#How_to_set_the_SSLSocketFactory_on_a_https_connection__in_order) stated in ksoap2 wiki.

This is the way I create a keyStore

```
    MainActivity.java
    // Get an instance of the Bouncy Castle KeyStore format
    try {
        this.keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
    } catch (KeyStoreException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    // Get the raw resource, which contains the keystore with
    // your trusted certificates (root and any intermediate certs)
    InputStream in = this.getApplicationContext().getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.myCer);
    try {
        // Initialize the keystore with the provided trusted certificates
        // Also provide the password of the keystore
        this.keyStore.load(in, "myPass".toCharArray());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    try {
        this.sslSocketFactory = new ConnectionWithSelfSignedCertificate(this.keyStore).getSSLSocketFactory();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And this is a code from AsyncTask

```
background task
final HttpsTransportSE transportSE = new HttpsTransportSE(URL, PORT, SERVICE, TIMEOUT);

    try {
        ((HttpsServiceConnectionSE) transportSE.getServiceConnection()).setSSLSocketFactory(this.sslSocketFactory);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

If I call transportSE.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope); I get IOException, Hostname 'www.marpel.cz' was not verified. What do I do wrong?

I have an ICS 4.1.2 device.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, do you use self signed certificate?

If yes, then follow this link: [android-webservices-via-ksoap2-https](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/mobile-development/threads/367301/android-webservices-via-ksoap2-https)

You need extra classes for creating https connection and accepting of the certificate. When everything is prepared, you can call your `transportSE`.

Answer (score 0):

The code in my first post works fine. I have found out that the self-signed certificate was issued for different domain. I fixed the certificate and everything works fine.

The fixed certificate runs here https://www.marpel.cz:445/

Thank you, Martin.