# WP8, Consuming SOAP with self-signed certificate

Tags: c#, soap, certificate, windows-phone-8, self-signed

I am able to consume a webservice over SOAP. However, I would like to use an https connection with a self-signed certificate.

How can I force my app to use my certificate? I was able to achieve [the same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15005360/self-signed-certificate) with Android.

Thank you, Martin.

Answer (score 0):

A working example from one of my projects. 
I'm not really sure if it will work on WP8, but on desktop everything works fine.

Here is the service class.

```
internal class PermissiveCertificatePolicy
{
    private string _subjectName;
    private static PermissiveCertificatePolicy _currentPolicy;

    public PermissiveCertificatePolicy(string subjectName)
    {
        _subjectName = subjectName;
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += RemoteCertValidate;
    }

    public static void Enact(string subjectName)
    {
        _currentPolicy = new PermissiveCertificatePolicy(subjectName);
    }

    private bool RemoteCertValidate(object sender, X509Certificate cert,
        X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors error)
    {
        return cert.Subject == _subjectName;
    }
}
```

Here is the example of usage:

```
namespace WcfClient
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private const string RCertName = "CN=WMSvc-WIN-R0NU6K5QG87";

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            PermissiveCertificatePolicy.Enact(RCertName);

            using (MyClient proxy = new MyClient("Ws2007HttpBinding_IHistory"))
            {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm afraid ServicePointManager is not available for WP8.